# PhantomJsDriver Capture Error On Site

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I used phantomjs version 2.x and PhantomJsDriver 1.3.0.

And my code down here.

```js
String cli_args[] = new String[]{
"--web-security=false",
"--ssl-protocol=any",
"--ignore-ssl-errors=true",
"--webdriver-loglevel=DEBUG"
};

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
capabilities.setCapability("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A542a Safari/419.3");
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cli_args);
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");

PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("https://m.naver.com");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\"nav\"]/div[3]/nav/ul/li[1]/a")).click();

new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id="nmap_news_1"]/a")));

------- NOT Found: GAVE UP. error

new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id="nmap_news_1"]/a/span/img")));

------- NOT Found: GAVE UP. error

WebElement creativeElem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id="nmap_news_1"]/a"));

------- NOT Found: GAVE UP. error
```

and phantomjs Error Message ->

1. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Audio
2. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.srcElement.tagName.toUpperCase')
3. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'naver.main.myteam.init')

I need get this Elements.

```html
<div id="nmap_news_1" class="ad" data-unit="1120D" data-tb="NEWS_1" data-extra="" data-mdom-unit="1120H" data-mdom="true" data-dom-url="http://mv.ad.naver.com/adshow" data-da-revision="161128111917755" data-position-type="rel" data-position-index="0" data-position-computed-index="7"><a href="https://mv.ad.naver.com/adclick?unit=1120D&amp;ac=7295638&amp;src=2984824&amp;br=2377222&amp;tb=NEWS_1&amp;rk=WDvKYQpjaWgAADt1PpUAAAFd&amp;eltts=oUooYL2N5fMvr1oK0dRHnw%3D%3D&amp;x_dy=828&amp;x_ih=521&amp;x_th=85&amp;x_iv=0" style="display:block;background:#fff;text-decoration:none;"><span id="nbp_da_img" style="display:block;width:100%;height:85px;background:url(https://ssl.pstatic.net/tveta/libs/1143/1143047/20161101160143-ebDDLUF3_bg_left.jpg) repeat-x;background-size:auto 85px;-webkit-background-size:1px 85px;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;font-size:0;"><img src="https://ssl.pstatic.net/tveta/libs/1143/1143047/20161101160143-ebDDLUF3.jpg" alt="AD" width="320" height="85" data-media-width="640" data-media-height="170" data-content-type="image" data-bakery="material" style="vertical-align:top;border:none" onload="naver_corp_da.logParamManager['nmap_news_1'].imgOnloadHandler();">&nbsp;</span></a></div>
```

and my code get Element is down here:

```
<div id="nmap_news_1" class="ad ready" data-unit="1120D" data-tb="NEWS_1" data-extra="" data-mdom-unit="1120H" data-mdom="true" data-dom-url="http://mv.ad.naver.com/adshow" data-da-revision="161128111917755" data-position-type="rel" data-position-index="0" data-position-computed-index="7">
<span class="ad_load">
</span>
</div>
```

Anyone know why this is so?

Comment: In conclusion, what I want to do is to capture an ad banner at https://m.naver.com.

Comment: you may want to edit that last bit into the question body.

Comment: I am trying to fetch the element of https://m.naver.com site with phantomjs but it seems that javascript is not executed correctly and error occurs. Could you help me to write the code to capture after all the elements of the first page have been loaded and connected to the site?

Comment: I don't know phantom js, so there really isn't much I can see wrong with this. Sorry